# Push notification in ios - Badging and Banner showing different request

Tags: ios, push-notification, push, apple-push-notifications

I have enabled the push notification in my product.currently it shows the badging. Now I want to implement the another notification in the same product but different response. I mean,

One request send the response for the badge notification
second request send the response the banner notification. Is it possible to do it ios?

Please guide me. I can do it only one at time. But How can I do it both ?

THanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you'd like to do.
If you want to send a single push notification that contains both badge and alert, simply put both badge and alert in your JSON payload :

```
{

    "aps" : {

        "alert" : "You got your emails.",

        "badge" : 9

    }

}
```

You have to register for both types of notifications in your app :

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)app {

   // other setup tasks here....

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

}
```

Now when you send a push notification, the badge number will be modified and the alert will be displayed.